# Iterated elimination of dominated strategies

Tags: game-theory, economics

I have a simple question that I am struggling to think about,
If a strategy survives IEDS does this it must be a best response?
For example the following game:

```
  L |   C | R
```

U | 9,5 | 7,1 | 0,6

M | 8,0 | 6,0 | 1,1

D | 9,0 | 6,2 | 0,1

By doing IEDS the solutions is (M,R) which in this case is a best response. Is this always the case?
Many thanks.

Comment: Give an example what you mean.

Comment: Edit initial question regarding comment